# How can I remove Alert function from ListIem component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (ListItem.js), which shows some photos from an API request.
Inside the same component I have a function called **showAlert**, that also uses some data from the API request and shows them in an alert dialog.
To invoke the showAlert function I use this line:

```
onClick={() => this.showAlert()}
```

**This is the whole component (simplified):**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert";

class ListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    alert: null // initialising an empty alert
  };

  showAlert() {
    const getAlert = () => (
      <SweetAlert confirmBtnBsStyle="info" onConfirm={() => this.closeAlert()}>
        <img src={this.props.photo.urls.small} />
      </SweetAlert>
    );

    this.setState({
      alert: getAlert() // Fire up the dialog box
    });
  }

  closeAlert() {
    this.setState({
      alert: null // colse the dialog window
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="card__body">
          <img
            src={this.props.photo.urls.small}
            onClick={() => this.showAlert()}
          />
        </div>
        {this.state.alert}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```

I want to remove the showAlert function and put it in a separate component, so I can use it in different components.

For this I created a new component called Alert.js, cut the **showAlert** function and the state, put them inside the Alert.js and exported it.

Then inside ListItem.js, I imported the Alert component and replaced this line:

```
{this.state.alert}
```

With this line:

```
<Alert photoPath={this.props.photo.urls.small} />
```

But what I don't know is, how can I invoke showAlert funcion, which is inside the Alert.js (child component) from the ListItem.js (parent component)?

The question is: How can I invoke a function inside the child component from the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trigger function calls from the parent. In that situation, what you want to do is pass the function `showAlert` as a prop to the `Alert` component, and bind `this` to the parent component and trigger it when needed in the parent.